# Concatinating and Counting Fields in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, count, virtual

I am trying to find count and concatinate that count in my field but it is giving error message as can't find make_count and I have created the same field above.

```
$this->Car->virtualFields['make_count'] = 'COUNT(Car.car_make)';
$this->Car->virtualFields['make_concat']='CONCAT(Car.car_make,Car.make_count)';

$models = array_unique($this->Car->find('list',array(  
                'fields' => array('Car.car_make', 'Car.make_concat'),
                'conditions'=>array('Car.ad_status'=>'saved'),
                'order'=>array('Car.car_make'=>'Asc'),
                'contain'=>false,
                'group'=>array('Car.car_make')
            )
));
```

Comment: I got the solution, I changed the code to :$this->Car->virtualFields['make_count'] = 'CONCAT(Car.car_make, " (", COUNT(Car.car_make), ")")';

   


   $models = array_unique($this->Car->find('list',array(  
     'fields' => array('Car.car_make', 'Car.make_count'),
     'conditions'=>array('Car.ad_status'=>'saved'),
     'order'=>array('Car.car_make'=>'Asc'),
     'contain'=>false,
     'group'=>array('Car.car_make')
    )
   ));

Comment: Please create an answer, and accept it. don't write a comment like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try:
$this->Car->virtualFields['make_concat']='CONCAT(Car.car_make,COUNT(Car.car_make))';

$models = array_unique($this->Car->find('list',array(  
                'fields' => array('Car.car_make', 'Car.make_concat'),
                'conditions'=>array('Car.ad_status'=>'saved'),
                'order'=>array('Car.car_make'=>'Asc'),
                'contain'=>false,
                'group'=>array('Car.car_make')
            )
));
```